How does the truthiness of null == 0 (false), null > 0 (false), null >= 0 (true) make sense?
I've seen a lot of the "haha js truthiness is wacky" examples over the years, but I just came across this one and I'm scratching my head:

null == 0 (false)
null >  0 (false)
null >= 0 (true!)

Even if we're coercing null to be 0 in the last one (>=), why isn't it being coerced in the first one (==)?
(I performed these operations in Chrome inspector console, if that perhaps changes anything)

btw, null <= 0 is also true.

Your question is answered here - so while null == 0 is false due to a specific rule, when you do null <= 0 or null >= 0 then the null is coerced to 0 and 0 <= 0 is true, as is 0 >= 0.
